# Django 4.1+ and Celery DB connection already closed

Tags: django, celery

Django 4.1 introduced https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#conn-health-checks, and when used in conjunction with `CONN_MAX_AGE` I've run into occasional Celery errors of the form  `Couldn't apply scheduled task xxx: connection already closed`

I have a workaround in my celery.py file (I happen to know of this solution because I also use Django's ORM in Flask, and it has the same issues):

```
@task_prerun.connect                                                                                                    
def on_task_prerun(sender=None, headers=None, body=None, **kwargs):                                                     
    close_old_connections()
```

I can't find anyone else experiencing the same issue, and before I create a PR for Celery I wanted to check with others first. Anyone else seen something similar?